# How can I update datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've two tables with foreign key, first is:

**tblFile** : FileID, FileName...

And Second is:

**tblChild** (in Datagridview) : ChildID, ChildName, ChildBirthDate, fkFileID.

> When click button Save (in Form), how can I Update All rows in second table if Add or Edit or Delete rows?
> (Form ex: https://i.postimg.cc/jq7Ks3CW/1.jpg)

I tried this code and others:

```
string ChID;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ChildID FROM tblChild WHERE ChildID = @ChildID", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildID", dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rowCh in dgv.Rows)
        {
            ChID = dt.Rows[0]["ChildID"].ToString();
            if (ChID == rowCh.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdCh = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblChild SET ChildName = @ChildName, ChildBirthDate = @ChildBirthDate, fkFileID = (SELECT FileID FROM tblFile WHERE FileID = @FileID) WHERE ChildID = @ChildID", ClsDB.con))
                {
                    cmdCh.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmdCh.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildID", rowCh.Cells[0].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmdCh.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildName", rowCh.Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmdCh.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildBirthDate", rowCh.Cells[2].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmdCh.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileID", txtID.Text.Trim());
                    cmdCh.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rowCh in dgv.Rows)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdCh = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblChild (ChildName, ChildBirthDate, fkFileID) VALUES (@ChildName, @ChildBirthDate, (SELECT FileID FROM tblFile WHERE FileID = @FileID))", ClsDB.con))
            {
                cmdCh.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildName", rowCh.Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                cmdCh.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildBirthDate", rowCh.Cells[2].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                cmdCh.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileID", txtID.Text.Trim());
                cmdCh.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The DbDataAdapter's job is primarily to *save* changes, not just load them. Why aren't you using it?

Comment: Thanks for your replying, I feel that what i tried is wrong, how can i using it?

Comment: It might help of you could give some more detail on your problem. You tried this code....and what happened / what should happen?

Comment: Is that so hard? the question is clear.. How Save All Changes in DGV (Add, Edit, Delete) at once when click button Save ???